# Is this sentence "Two workers are facing the axe" well rephrased?

Tags: meaning

Original:

> Two workers are facing the axe.

Rephrasing:

> Two workers are facing a possible dismissal.

Comment: Rephrased? How was it phrased at first?

Comment: I mean if "Two workers are facing a possible dismissal" is a well rephrasing for "Two workers are facing the axe".

Comment: Ah; that wasn't very clear, sorry.

Comment: Until a real answer comes in, I think that the second sentence is more specific. The first can also mean they're being demoted or something. Or even, if the story takes place in the Middle Ages, that they're facing the axe.

Comment: I agree with Mr. Lister (who is refreshingly polite) that there can be multiple meanings, and context would be the determining factor if you used "facing the axe".

Comment: That sounds like a decent rephrasing to me – so long as the workers aren't [lumberjacks](http://content.artofmanliness.com/uploads//2010/07/axe.jpg).

Comment: @Jim I'm not sure if I should feel insulted or not...

Comment: Not at all. Keep it up.

Comment: To my ear "dismissal" carries the connotation of firing for misconduct. If you want to imply the loss of jobs due to a company's financial woes, I would use "facing possible *redundancy*".

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully No, you can be dismissed for any reason.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not which is better phrased but what is the audience you're trying to reach.

If you mean to sensationalize the situation in an effort to emphasize the outrage of their potential firing, by all means use "facing the axe."

If, on the other hand, you are making some kind of official report to higher-ups (and you care what they think of you), use the "dismissal" phrasing.

It's all a matter of audience register and your intent.

Comment: You're certainly right about "axe" being a "loaded" term, but it's also very much an *informal* usage. You'd still use the word "dismissal" if you were sympathetically addressing a staff meeting where you regretfully need to "let a couple of people go". I'm sure that's what you meant by "register", but you didn't explicitly say it.

Answer (score 1):

In "Two workers are facing a possible dismissal", the words *a possible* are unnecessary and undesirable.  That is, "Two workers are facing dismissal" corresponds more closely to "Two workers are facing the axe" than does the more-wordy version.

Answer (score 0):

If the dismissal is only possible, not certain, I think you're better off with "Two workers are in danger of being axed" or "Two workers are at risk of being axed," than with "Two workers are facing the axe." To my mind, "facing the axe" seems more suitable to a person who is on the verge of dismissal (or execution), like late-stage Anne Boleyn, though some people undoubtedly do use it more loosely to refer to a mere risk of such doom.